# TypeScript and module option set to es2015/es2020/esnext

Tags: typescript, commonjs, es6-modules

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
    }
}
```

and my file `test.ts`:

```
module.exports.a = 4;
```

Then I run `yarn tsc` and surpisingly in my output file `test.js` I still have

```
module.exports.a = 4;
```

Question: Why the content of output file is not using esnext modules? Why isn't it `export const a = 4`?

Btw, if I go other way - `module` set to `commonjs` and `test.ts` with `export const a = 4` the output file is generated correctly with cjs modules.

Why ts can compile modules from es to cjs and not from cjs to es ? If indeed TS can not do it then why do we have module option anyway?